# aspnet core dnx MVC Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net

I try to use dnx scaffolding template on visual studio code on mac using "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final" and I have added the "gen" command using "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration". But it seems not going well after I type in terminal :

dnx gen controller -name HelloController

I got the following error:

```
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
There was an error running the template /Users/tebe/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc/1.0.0-rc1-
final/Templates/ControllerGenerator/EmptyController.cshtml: Template Processing 
Failed:error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information 
-- 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be missing namespace in model classes and/or their definitions in DbContext class.

```
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

BTW, have you created models for your controllers generator? Please check the below "full" gen example:

```
dnx gen controller -name BookController --dataContext ApplicationDbContext --model Book
```

Please read this thing carefully: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html#entity-framework